# Como colocar o caret (cursor) na posição certa?

Tags: codeblocks

Quando eu crio um novo método, fica assim:

```
void teste(){|}
```

Perceba que o cursor está entre `{}`, e quando eu pressiono enter fica assim:

```
void teste(){
|}
```

Agora o cursor está atrás da `}`, e esse é meu problema.
O ideal seria que o cursor se comportasse da mesma forma que ele faz quando utilizo o método `if()`, que é assim:

```
if(){|}
```

E quando eu pressiono enter:

```
if(){
   |
}
```

Perceba que o cursor agora está exatamente onde eu começo a escrever meu código. Como eu faço pra que isso, que acontece no `if()`, aconteça com qualquer método que eu criar? Como alterar esse comportamento do cursor?

Estou usando o codeblocks 16.01,

Comment: :( forever alone